# how does all the existing directories get mounted at the mount point when using FUSE?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, fuse, deduplication

I'm trying to build a new filesystem with deduplication using FUSE.

I tried running the `fusexmp_fh.c` provided in the example section of the FUSE. However after mounting the filesystem at a mount point, I can see all the existing directories inside the mount point. I dont need those directories. **I want the mounted filesystem to be empty.**

I tried searching through `fusexmp_fh.c` but could not find out where the existing directories get added.

- Can someone explain to me how this works?

Also

- can `fusexmp_fh.c` be taken as a base for building the filesystem?
- Does it have all the basic functionalities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying that you mounted the file system over a non-empty directory, and you can see the previous contents of the directory?  (In which case, the answer is "don't mount to a non-empty mount point".  Usually it throws an error to tell you not to do that.)

If what you're seeing is the directories and files in the directory that you are using as your base directory, that's the normal behavior for a loopback file system, which is what `fusexmp_fh.c` is.  The example file system takes a mount point, and passes all commands on that mount point through to a backing directory.  If you use a backing directory that has files in it, you will now see those files in two places, the original location and the mounted fuse directory.

If you want to understand how the directory filling works, start by taking a look at `readdir`, and see how the `stat` items that it returns are constructed.  Each of those is a single directory entry.

Yes, you can use `fusexmp_fh.c` as the basis for a basic file system, it's got all the necessary pieces, although extended metadata isn't supported. (But adding it is fairly trivial for a loopback.)

Comment: I mounted the file system on an empty directory. But after mounting when I do ls it has all these directories. `xx@xxx:/tmp/fs$ ls ->
bin    dev   initrd.img      lost+found  opt   run      srv  usr      vmlinuz.old boot   etc   initrd.img.old  media       proc  sbin     sys  var cdrom  home  lib             mnt         root  selinux  tmp  vmlinuz`. I basically want the mount point to be empty after mounting my filesystem. where exactly does these directories gets added?

Comment: So it sounds like when you mount it, it's doing a loop back file system pointed to the `/` directory of your root file system.  Try running fusexmp_fh with `-o subdir=DIR` where DIR is the name of some empty directory where you want your data to be stored.